# Imageview on the top of cardview

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have circular `imageview` that I need to align above `cardview` but it should be like half circle of the image will be outside the `cardview` and remaining half circle of the image to be inside `cardview`. Like top border center of `cardview` will have circular `imageview` present on it.

How can I do this, I will be unable to upload image because my proxy dont allow me sorry for inconvenience.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try out this code

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_contacts"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_contacts_36px"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/ll_cardView"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="center|top" />
```

change app:layout_anchor id name to your card view id.

Comment: @eLemEnt , nice :D

Comment: In order to make this work, you'll need CoordinatorLayout as parent

Answer (score 4):

This can be done like so.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.simplebox.demo.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/first"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/cardview_default_radius"
        app:cardElevation="4dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:background="#FFF000">
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Output will be. Use Circular ImageView for round Image.

[image]

Comment: still imageview is behind the card

Comment: remove this line from cardview properties     app:cardElevation="4dp"

Answer (score 2):

Do it as follows

```
<FrameLayout>

    <CardView> //set marginTop of 10 dp so that it will be half the height of CirccularImageView

    <CircularImageView> //set some height to it like 20dp and gravity center horizontal.
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work in your case.

```
        <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/volume"
            android:translationZ="6dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<CardView> //set marginTop of 10 dp so that it will be half the height of CirccularImageView

<CircularImageView> //set some height to it like 20dpand gravity center horizontal.
```

// also give some elevation to